# Delete a row from MYSQL database table based on variable ID using PHP button in FORM

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, post, video

I work on a website where you can add tags to a video. this screenshot should give you an overview how the result should look like:

http://www.unistamp.ch/images/images.html

A video with comments is embeded and to the right there is an Iframe where the detailed information for the comments on the timeline are accessed from a MYSQL database.
Here a screenshot of the video_comment table.

I want to delete a specific comment from the database based on his comment ID.
I tried this code but it doesnt work to pass the commentid by clicking the X button:

```
<?php
include '../../../DB/MySql/connectVideoPhase.php';

//****** Delete Row in table
if(isset($_POST['X']))
{
    $comment_id = $_POST['comment_id'];
    //CHeck --> doesnt work
    echo "<pre> commentid= ".$comment_id . "</pre> ";
    $sql = "DELETE video_converted_comment ".
               "WHERE commentid = \"".$comment_id."\" ;";
    $retval = mysql_query( $sql);

    if(! $retval )
    {   
        die('Could not delete data: ' . mysql_error()); }
        echo "Deleted data successfully\n";
    }
    //**************************************

    //******* Get the comments  
    $video_id = $_REQUEST['VideoId'];
    // for testing use a specific video ID
    if (! $video_id) {
        $video_id = '153fb143';
    }

    $sqlSelectComment = "Select * from video_converted_comment WHERE videoid ='".$video_id."'";
    $sqlComments = mysql_query($sqlSelectComment);
    $i = mysql_num_rows($sqlSelectComment);
    // *************************

    //********* Fill Table
    echo "

<table width=\"100\" border=\"1\" >
<tr>
<td width=\"25\"><b>start</b></td>
<td width=\"25\"><b>end</b></td>
<td width=\"75\"><b>Text</b></td>
<td width=\"5\"><b>X</b></td>
<td width=\"0\"><input type=\"hidden\"></td>
</tr>"; 

    while ($comments = mysql_fetch_array($sqlComments))
    {

        echo "<tr><td>" .$comments['starttime'] ."</td>";
        echo "<td>" .$comments['endtime'] ."</td>";
        echo "<td>" .$comments['text'] ."</td>";
        echo "<td> <form method=\"post\" action=\"".$_PHP_SELF ."\"> 
        <input name=\"comment_id\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"".$comments['id']."\">  
        <button name=\"X\"  type=\"submit\" value=\"".$comments['id']."\">  </td>
        </form>";
    }
echo "</table> ";
```

Any help on deleting/ adding comments to the DB based on a commentid using PHP would be very appreciated! 
Would it be easier to do it with javascript? The visualisation of the timeline below the video is done with javascript.

Comment: Do you see an error or does the comment just not get deleted?

Comment: its `$PHP_SELF`, not `$_PHP_SELF`. also it is deprecated, instead use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`

Comment: This is copy & paste (=not your) code ... what did you try yourrself to solve the problem?

Comment: thanks for the hint with $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']

Comment: I try to pass the ID of a comment = comments['id'] after i klicked on the button. So when it reloads the same script again it deletes the entry with the ID in the Database.

Comment: @Jim   I get the error that the SQL statement is wrong. it's Select * from video_converted_comment WHERE videoid =""  --> no commentid passed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing around with that quite a while the code is working now.

After klicking the delte button in the table the script deletes the row in the MySQL table.

**Mistake nr. 1** was: the whole table is displayed in an Iframe. when it's included on the site

```
<iframe id=\"commentTable\" src=\"DB/MySql/CommentTableAndDelete.php?VideoId=".$ID."..
```

The Id is passed in the url and accessed by

```
                    $video_id = $_REQUEST['VideoId'];
```

This doesn't work when the script loads itself after deleting an entry because the method of the form is "post".

This might be not the best way to do it but it works:

```
        $video_id = $_REQUEST['VideoId'];
                // if script loads itself
                if (! $video_id) {
                $video_id = $_POST['VideoId'];
                }
```

**Mistake nr. 2** was the form. Somehow it didn't pass the variable because of a Typo
This works:

`<form method=\"post\" action=\"".$_PHP_SELF ."\"> 
                <input id=\"comment_id\" name=\"comment_id\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"".$comments['commentid']."\">

                <button name=\"X\"  type=\"submit\" value=\"X\">`

**Mistake nr. 3** The Sql Statement was not correct. I tested it in phpmyadmin before pasting the statement to the php code.

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM video_converted_comment WHERE commentid='".$comment_id."' ;";
```

The working code:

```
        //******* Get the comments  
                    $video_id = $_REQUEST['VideoId'];

                    if (! $video_id) {
                    $video_id = $_POST['VideoId'];
                    }


                    $sqlSelectComment = "Select * from video_converted_comment WHERE videoid ='".$video_id."';";
                    $sqlComments = mysql_query($sqlSelectComment);
                    if(! $sqlComments )
                    {   die('Could not get Comments from DB: ' . mysql_error()); }

                    $i = mysql_num_rows($sqlSelectComment);
    // *************************

    //****** Delete Row in table
    //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15843678/mssql-and-php-select-specific-row-based-on-which-button-is-clicked
        if(isset($_POST['X']))
        {
        $comment_id = $_POST['comment_id'];
        //CHeck
        //echo "<pre> commentid= ".$comment_id . "</pre> ";

        $sql = "DELETE FROM video_converted_comment WHERE commentid='".$comment_id."' ;";
        $retval = mysql_query( $sql);


        if(! $retval )
        {   die('Could not delete data: ' . mysql_error()); }
        echo "Deleted data successfully\n";
        }
        //**************************************

//********* Fill Table
echo "

<table width=\"100\" border=\"1\" >
<tr>
<td width=\"25\"><p>start</p></td>
<td width=\"25\"><p>end</p></td>
<td width=\"100\"><p>Text</p></td>
<td width=\"10\"><p>X</p></td>
</tr>"; 

    while ($comments = mysql_fetch_array($sqlComments))
        {

        echo "<tr><td>" . gmdate("i:s", $comments['starttime']) ."</td>";
        echo "<td>" . gmdate("i:s", $comments['endtime']) ."</td>";
        echo "<td>" .$comments['text']."</td>";
        echo "<td> <form method=\"post\" action=\"".$_PHP_SELF ."\"> 
                <input id=\"comment_id\" name=\"comment_id\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"".$comments['commentid']."\">  
                <button name=\"X\"  type=\"submit\" value=\"X\">  </td>
                </form>";
        }
echo "</table> ";

?>
```

Comment: After I have the php code working I tried to do it with ajax. As I am a novice in that area I have some difficulties. I tried to put the code to delete the row into a seperate php file. But somehow it won't be executed I think. I adapted the example from [link]http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_database.asp   but somehow it doesnt call the php file. does anybody know how to learn easily ajax basics or has an idea how to solve this problem using ajax?